# ssis package not executing on its own through sql server jobs

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis, nullreferenceexception

I have an ssis package in which I am converting an excel file into csv file through the script task in visual studio 13 c-sharp .It should automatically pick the excel file and convert it into the csv through converter code and push into sql server db.
I have created a job in sql server that should run that ssis package .But every morning I get an error as below:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>   at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Object o)
>   at ST_30876fcf7c394e70be7554

when I try to run the job overnight. But when I manually run the job it pick the file through jobs and push it into the database perfectly.
Can you tell me what could be the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Does the user that the SQL Agent job is running as have permission to see/read/write the files you're asking it to operate on?

Comment: The log should also mention which step failed. What type of step is it?

Comment: Your c# code probably references a library that is not installed on the SQL Server. Let me guess... Excel?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it is possible to make excel > csv conversion in SSIS without installing Excel on Sql Sserver? I believed, that referencing library solves this...

Comment: I don’ t know which library you’re using. You didn’t post any code